# React overrides the locale

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

When I change the route or reload the page then the language resets.

On the console I get this log message:

```
i18next: languageChanged en
```

I think it happens due to this call:

```
const { i18n } = useTranslation();
```

How can I tell it to use the locale I stored (let's say in the variable `locale`) instead of guessing all over again?

Comment: how did you initialize i18n instance? the `init` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on component mount update the locale then use the same.

```
function LanguageSelector() {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  // Load the saved locale from localStorage or use a default value
  const savedLocale = localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'en';

  // Set the initial language when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(savedLocale);
  }, [i18n, savedLocale]);

  const changeLanguage = (language) => {
    // Save the selected locale to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('locale', language);

    // Change the language
    i18n.changeLanguage(language);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>English</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('es')}>Español</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the `useEffect()`.